# Importing object values as key value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have seen people importing variables as key-value pairs from objects. I do not understand where the value part comes from?

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width: totalWidth } = Dimensions.get("window");
```

What is totalWidth in this case? Where does it come from?

Comment: That line is the same as `const totalWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;` however that deconstruction syntax allows you to declare multiple variables at once. It's just about renaming the `const`.

Comment: Give a read to [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), especially to [Object Destrcuturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). Those links will help you to understand how it works...

Answer (score 4):

It's what they refer to as **[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operatoren/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)**. So:

```
const { width: totalWidth } = Dimensions.get("window");
```

**`width`** refers to the property name and the **`totalWidth`** the variable you want to store this in.

You can assign multiple property values in this manner to new variables:

```
const { width: totalWidth, height: totalHeight } = Dimensions.get("window");
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
const  totalWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
const  totalHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
```

Essentially just a neat way to reassign property values to variables in a single line.

Answer (score 3):

The second-line is not an import. What they're doing is declaring a new variable. They are destructuring the object returned from `Dimensions.get("window")`. In layman's terms we can say they're extracting some named-data from the output. Then they use the semi-colon to rename it to something else.

```
const { width: totalWidth } = Dimensions.get("window");
```

The object returned might look like this:

```
{ width: 100, height: 200 }
```

So they took the key-value pair of **width**, and created a new variable:

```
const width = 100
```

Then they renamed **width** to **totalWidth**:

```
const totalWidth = 100
```

That sequence is all done in one short, nice-line.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you for the explanation. The person had a width variable declared a few lines down, I think he just wanted to change the name of width.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { width: totalWidth } = Dimensions.get("window");
```

I have tried using the same code as above but its not working.
you actually no need to use like this..

Replace with `const { width , height } = Dimensions.get("window");`
and try to console width and height.

Here width and height is key respective to value of : `Dimensions.get("window").width;` and  `Dimensions.get("window").height;`